# Launched H2O server but some issue with the web version

Tags: r, h2o

I am trying to launch H2O server in R which works fine after I type in

```
h2o.init()
```

However, when I open 127.0.0.1:54321 in the browser, the following comes up. How do I find what is the problem here and hence the solution?

[image]

Comment: Proxy is disabled. firewall, not sure why that would be an issue because it's a localhost connection. Could internet explorer settings be a problem?

Comment: Windows + IE. Might be. Need Windows users

Comment: unfortunately i will not be alter any firewall type settings. is there any other way to confirm this?

Comment: Try starting h2o outside R and see if that works.

Comment: Have you tried another browser, like Firefox?

Comment: Also, hitting F12 and reloading the browser should show any error messages on the browser's console.